# how to get browser window object using java script or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get window object of the already open window and I don't want to open a new window when expected window is closed.

I tried the following option:

```
var windowObj = window.open('','windowName', '');
```

However it opens a new window when expected window is not present/closed.

Please suggest me something to get the window object using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Do you mean THE already open window, or do you mean ANOTHER named open window?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to keep the references of opened windows when calling the `window.open` function. It is not possible to acquire a reference otherwise.

A solution would be to create a new window only when the previous one was closed, or reuse it otherwise. Something like :

```
var _childWin = null;

function getChildWin() {
   if (_childWin == null || _childWin.closed) {
       _childWin = window.open(...);
   }
   return _childWin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just `var windowObj = window;` ?  You don't even need to assign it to your own variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are really two ways to get "window"

```
var thisWindow = window; // window script resides
var newOpenWindow = window.open(parameters for window here);// window opened
```

For the newOpenWindow, you can check if it exists prior to opening it (did you do the "open" already basically) by looking for a false value

```
if (newOpenWindow) // if true it is open
```

Other windows, you would not be able to detect from a script standpoint as they are out of scope of the script within a window/browser instance once they are opened.

There is also the "contained window" which is really a document within an iframe, which is really a different matter altogether.

EDIT: Illustrate window interaction

Create a child window named TestCallBack.html

Note jQuery in both windows.

Show some functional interaction between the windows (passing from child, the window and a jQuery object of the new windows document):

Child window layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>iamchild</title>
    <script src="JS/jQuery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JS/TestCallBack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  Howdy
  <div id="achildy">HereIBe
    <div id="inchildy">
      I am childy text
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

text of the TestCallBack.js file:

```
var ct;
function childCallBack(passstuff)
{
    alert('ct:"' + ct + '" CHILD GOT:(' + passstuff + ")");
    return ct;
};
$(document).ready(function()
{
    ct = $("#achildy").text();
    window.opener.logNewWindow(window, $(document));
});
```

Javascript in parent window to open child window: (and function for child to call)

```
function logNewWindow(newWindow, JQnewWindowDoc)
{
    var mychildText = JQnewWindowDoc.text();//all the child doc text
    var innerChildText = $("#inchildy", JQnewWindowDoc).text();// one element text
    var gotback = newWindow.childCallBack("CHILD TEXT:" + mychildText + " INNER:" + innerChildText);
    alert("GOT:" + gotback); //child sent me this text from childCallBack
};

var AWindow = window.open("TestCallBack.html");
```